# Java Garbage Collector odd behavior

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I encountered this weird behavior in java GC.

We have an application with a max heap of 1GB and it was causing GC overhead limit exceeded errors.

Here follows the jmap -heap output for that;

> ```
> Heap Configuration:
>   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
>   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
>   MaxHeapSize              = 1610612736 (1536.0MB)
>   NewSize                  = 1572864 (1.5MB)
>   MaxNewSize               = 536870912 (512.0MB)
>   OldSize                  = 1072168960 (1022.5MB)
>   NewRatio                 = 2
>   SurvivorRatio            = 8
>   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
>   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
>   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
>   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)
> ```

```
Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 37224448 (35.5MB)
   used     = 34328776 (32.73847198486328MB)
   free     = 2895672 (2.7615280151367188MB)
   92.2210478446853% used
From Space:
  capacity = 1572864 (1.5MB)
  used     = 786432 (0.75MB)
  free     = 786432 (0.75MB)
  50.0% used
To Space:
  capacity = 1572864 (1.5MB)
  used     = 0 (0.0MB)
  free     = 1572864 (1.5MB)
  0.0% used
PS Old Generation
  capacity = 1072168960 (1022.5MB)
  used     = 13918336 (13.2735595703125MB)
  free     = 1058250624 (1009.2264404296875MB)
  1.2981476352383863% used
```

So we tuned the GC with following parameters;

> ```
> -XX:NewSize=512 
> -XX:MaxNewSize=512 
> -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 
> -XX:NewRatio=1
> ```

NewSize and MaxNewSize were supposed to be set in MBs.

But with this configuration, we get the following heap map.

> ```
> Heap Configuration:
>   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
>   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
>   MaxHeapSize              = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
>   NewSize                  = 1572864 (1.5MB)
>   MaxNewSize               = 1572864 (1.5MB)
>   OldSize                  = 1072168960 (1022.5MB)
>   NewRatio                 = 1
>   SurvivorRatio            = 16
>   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
>   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
>   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
>   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)
> ```

```
Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
  capacity = 524288 (0.5MB)
  used     = 200200 (0.19092559814453125MB)
  free     = 324088 (0.30907440185546875MB)
  38.18511962890625% used
From Space:
  capacity = 524288 (0.5MB)
  used     = 98304 (0.09375MB)
  free     = 425984 (0.40625MB)
  18.75% used
To Space:
  capacity = 524288 (0.5MB)
  used     = 0 (0.0MB)
  free     = 524288 (0.5MB)
  0.0% used
PS Old Generation
  capacity = 1072168960 (1022.5MB)
  used     = 522704656 (498.49000549316406MB)
  free     = 549464304 (524.0099945068359MB)
  48.752078776837564% used
```

Now the Eden space capacity is only 0.5MB but it only uses 38% of which was previously 92% and the capacity was 35MB.
And the Old Gen utilization has increased up to 50% which was previously around 2%.

Can anyone please explain why the GC behaves like this ?

Comment: *"NewSize and MaxNewSize were supposed to be set in MBs."* - then why aren't you setting them in MBs?

Comment: We have already set them. But want to know the reason for this aforementioned behavior .

Comment: What is the total available system memory and what values you set for  -Xms and -Xmx

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase, what gives you the idea that those parameters take their arguments in Megabytes?

Comment: The fact that the Eden space capacity being showed as 0.5MB and then 
here 
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/08/useful-jvm-flags-part-5-young-generation-garbage-collection/

and here 
http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2013/03/garbage-collection-tuning/

it is set as -XX:MaxNewSize=512m to indicate 512 MB.

Comment: And why downvoted the question ?

Comment: Another location 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the reason.

When the JVM tries to allocate heap for an object, it first checks for the available size of the corresponding TLAB (Thread Local Allocation Buffer) and if it isn't enough then tries to grow it. 
If the remaining size of the Eden space is not enough for the TLAB expansion, then the JVM looks for the Eden space itself. It the remaining size of the Eden space isn't enough too, then the JVM allocates the object directly in the Old Gen space.

Apart from that, if the NewGen size is smaller, then not only the Eden space but also both survivor spaces are smaller (usually 8 or 16 times) too. So even if the JVM manages to allocate space in the Eden space, if those objects manages to survive for a couple of minor collections. The survivor space would overflow and the would be moved to the OldGen space.